# Selecting items from a Listbox and displaying in ListView using C#, XAML

Tags: wpf, listview, listbox

I have 3 controls in a WPF window.. a textbox, listbox and listview.

The textbox is like a searching textbox, where i search for Folder's in a particular folder, the list of searched folders will be displayed in listbox. I am able to do until this part.

Now, if I select any of the displayed folders in the listbox, then the files available in the particular folder should be displayed in the ListView. (missing out the link b/w the 2 here).

eg : I have 3 folders displayed in listbox (say folder1, folder2, folder3).each folder has few excel files. I selected folder 2 ( which has 5 excel files, mark.xls, steve.xls, cary.xls, rick.xls and jenny.xls and also a subfolder inside that called Launch1).

Now, the List view should show the folder2 contents divided into 3 columns, ( col1, col2, col3).

```
Name                           Desc                                      Date

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Mark                     this is mark's excel                         07/20/2009

steve                    this is steve's excel.                       07/22/2009

cary                     .....................                        ..........

rick                     .....................                        ..........

jenny                    .....................                        ..........

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

+ Launch1
```

Again Launch1 folder might have few workbooks, so I have put a plus on it.. so when + is clicked.. it shuold display the files inside this folder.

I am using Xaml and C#... please help.

Now, the problem I am facing is.. if I search for the files which i have to display... I am able to get the files while debugging..( using Add watch..) , but I was not able to add the data to the ListView...

Thank You,

Ramm

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Hi Guys,
I am sorry if i have confused. Its an UI where, I am using ListView with ListView.View for the 3 columns like

Workbook, Description and Date...

I ve edited the query and added the xaml code..pls look into the query.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an anonymous type to get the job done:

```
private void btnUploadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  if (txtBxUploadTB.IsVisible) {
    var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\"); // just an example
    foreach (string file in files) {
      // I used dummy values, modify as appropriate
      lbFolders.Items.Add(new { AnyWorkbook = file, DescName = "descr", WorkbookDate = DateTime.Now });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Julien,
Thanks for the answer.. it solved a bit for me..
how to make the appearance in ListView as hierarchial view??

I mean, i have main folder (called Download).. it has subfolders called launch1(this has 5 excel files inside), launch2(this has 6 excel files), launch3(this 3 excel files) each.
so, when i load it thro the btnUploadButton_Click ( said above post). I like to have in a hierarchial way and I should be able to select the any excel file in any of the 3 folders.. which should open the excel file. when i provide the path to the btnUpload it will have the 3 folders

Pls helpme